# handle errors returned by controller in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, exception

I want to know how to handle errors via json response. 
In my controller code I am trying to create user but if there is any error while creating I want to pass a json response, and in ajax function I want to handle that error.

Can you please help me with this? I have tried like this and I don't know if it is right or not.

My controller function

```
 try {
    // Validate the value...
    \App\User::create([
        'user_firstname' => $request->input('user_firstname'),
        'user_lastname' => $request->input('user_lastname'),
        'user_phone' => $request->input('user_phone'),
        'username' => $request->input('user_username'),
        'email' =>$request->input('user_email'),
        'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
        'verifyToken' => Str::random(40)
          ]);
        throw new Exception();

  }  catch (Exception $e) {

         return response()->json(['error' => true,'message'=>'Something went wrong'],200);
 }
```

and my ajax function

```
error: function(error) {


        var JSONObject = JSON.parse(error.responseText);
        console.log(error);

        $.each(JSONObject.errors, function (key, val) {
            console.log(key);

                    $("#" + key + "_error").text(val[0]);
                    console.log(val[0]);
         });
         currentTab=0;
         $('#user-verify').css({display: "none"});
         $('#nextBtn').css({display: "block"});
         showTabIndividual(currentTab);
    }   
    });
```

Comment: "You don't know if it is right or wrong". Well? What do you get? An error? No error? Nothing?

Comment: i get an error Something went wrong

Comment: Ok, then it's working.